# Keras discard or ignore uncertain prediction result

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have successfully built a multi-classes CNN in Keras for image classification purpose. I am now ready to start prediction, but among the test images, there are some images, which do not belong to any of the labels, but it will still be mistakenly classified as one of the labels.

Here is my predict function:

```
def predict(img):
    x = img.resize((img_width, img_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    x = img_to_array(x)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    array = model.predict(x)
    result = array[0]
    answer = np.argmax(result)
    return answer
```

I am thinking to discard the prediction result if the max value of prediction result array is below a certain value, but I am not sure how small I should set it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need another training dataset to estimate the best threshold... or you can train a new model with an extra class for all theses images that do not have a label.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will probably not think about training a new model for those unlabeled images since they are too random, and I am curious about how to use another training set to estimate the threshold, can you provide more details?

Comment: Think of it like a second machine learning problem... you optimize your threshold on a training set to get the best accuracy in your test set.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I will definitely try your suggestion. Thanks.